# Comparing two numbers

Tags: java, double

I have this program piece:

```
double stockWeight = 1;
    if(data[0] > 9 )        
        stockWeight = 1000*R(data[0]/10);
    double compare = data[0]*100-stockWeight;
    System.out.println(compare);
    if(compare > 300.0 && compare <=600.0)
        stockWeight += 300;
    else if(compare > 600.0 && compare <= 900.0)
        stockWeight += 600;
    else if(compare > 900.0);
        stockWeight += 900;

        System.out.println(stockWeight);

 ///////////////////////////////////
   private int R(double D){
      int howBIG = 1;
      if (D >= 100){howBIG = 10;}
      else if(D >= 1000){howBIG = 100;}
      DecimalFormat F = new DecimalFormat("#");
      return Integer.valueOf(F.format(D/howBIG))*howBIG;
  }
```

the output is:

```
126.0
1900.0
```

All numbers here are double type. `data[0] = 11.26`
why does my computer think that 126.0 is greater than 900.0??
R method basically is div function of 10(100) if greater than 100(1000), gives whole number

Comment: Your code snippet includes some free-standing statements, and then a function.  How does this all run?  And your code only has a single `println()`, yet your output appears to have two separate lines...

Comment: Why are you using a ***bleedin' `DecimalFormat`*** to round a `double`? I suggest investigating [`java.lang.Math`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).

Comment: The indentation on this code is horrendous. Confusing and contradictory. p.s. with if (D >= 100){howBIG = 10;} else if(D >= 1000){howBIG = 100;}, the else clause will NEVER get executed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are likely seeing the confusing result because of the stray semicolon in your last else statement:

```
else if(compare > 900.0);
```

So this line doesn't depend on the `else` clause and will always be executed:

```
stockWeight += 900;
```

Essentially you will always add 900 to the stockWeight immediately before the last print statement, whether or not `compare > 900.0`.